# check whether matrix rows equal a vector in R , vectorized

Tags: r, matrix, vector, vectorization

I'm very surprised this question has not been asked, maybe the answer will clear up why.  I want to compare rows of a matrix to a vector and return whether the row == the vector everywhere.  See the example below.  I want a vectorized solution, no apply functions because the matrix is too large for slow looping.  Suppose there are many rows as well, so I would like to avoid repping the vector.

```
set.seed(1)

M = matrix(rpois(50,5),5,10)

v = c(3 ,   2 ,   7  ,  7 ,   4   , 4   , 7  ,  4  ,  5, 6)

M
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    4    8    3    5    9    4    5    6    7     7
[2,]    4    9    3    6    3    1    5    7    6     1
[3,]    5    6    6   11    6    4    5    2    7     5
[4,]    8    6    4    4    3    8    3    6    5     6
[5,]    3    2    7    7    4    4    7    4    5     6
```

Output should be

```
FALSE  FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One possibility is

```
rowSums(M == v[col(M)]) == ncol(M)
## [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Or simlarly

```
rowSums(M == rep(v, each = nrow(M))) == ncol(M)
## [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Or

```
colSums(t(M) == v) == ncol(M)
## [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

`v[col(M)]` is just a shorter version of `rep(v, each = nrow(M))` which creates a vector the same size as `M` (matrix is just a vector, try `c(M)`) and then compares each element against its corresponding one using `==`. Fortunately `==` is a generic function which has an `array` method (see `methods("Ops")` and `is.array(M)`) which allows us to run `rowSums` (or `colSums`) on it in order to makes sure we have the amount of matches as `ncol(M)`

Comment: I was hoping to avoid using rep() because M is a very very big matrix, so to make another one for this simple logical task will be burdensome.

Comment: Is `colSums(t(M) == v) == ncol(M)` better? It's not such "*simple logical task*" btw

Answer (score 5):

Using DeMorgan's rule (Not all = Some not), then All equal = Not Some Not equal, we also have

```
!colSums(t(M) != v)
```

Answer (score 0):

The package `prodlim` has a function called `row.match`, which is easy to use and ideal for your problem. First install and load the library: `library(prodlim)`. In our example, `row.match` will return '5' because the 5th row in `M` is equal to `v`. We can then convert this into a logical vector.

```
m <- row.match(v, M)
m==1:NROW(M)#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```