# Getting rows of a matrix which coincide with a series of vectors, without using apply

Tags: r, matrix, vector, vectorization, apply

My question is sort of related to [my earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32640682/check-whether-matrix-rows-equal-a-vector-in-r-vectorized).

Suppose I have one matrix and 4 vectors (can consider this another matrix, since the order of the vectors matters), and I want to get the row numbers which coincide to each vector, in order.  I would like the solution to avoid repeating vectors and be as efficient as possible, since the problem is large scale.

Example.

```
 set.seed(1)

    M = matrix(rpois(50,5),5,10)
    v1 = c(3, 2, 7, 7, 4, 4, 7,  4, 5, 6)
    v2=  c(8, 6,  4, 4, 3,  8,  3, 6, 5, 6)
    v3=  c(4,  8, 3,  5, 9, 4, 5,  6, 7 ,7)
    v4=  c(4,  9, 3, 6,  3, 1, 5, 7,6, 1)

Vmat = cbind(v1,v2,v3,v4)

M
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    4    8    3    5    9    4    5    6    7     7
[2,]    4    9    3    6    3    1    5    7    6     1
[3,]    5    6    6   11    6    4    5    2    7     5
[4,]    8    6    4    4    3    8    3    6    5     6
[5,]    3    2    7    7    4    4    7    4    5     6

Vmat
      v1 v2 v3 v4
 [1,]  3  8  4  4
 [2,]  2  6  8  9
 [3,]  7  4  3  3
 [4,]  7  4  5  6
 [5,]  4  3  9  3
 [6,]  4  8  4  1
 [7,]  7  3  5  5
 [8,]  4  6  6  7
 [9,]  5  5  7  6
[10,]  6  6  7  1
```

The output should be...

```
5 4 1 2
```

Comment: What does it mean to "avoid repeating vectors"?

Comment: I think `apply` is the right way to go, even though you don't like it. `m = apply(M,1,paste0,collapse="_"); v = apply(Vmat,2,paste0,collapse="_"); match(v,m)`

Comment: Frank, avoiding rep(v1,) to do some comparison.  If you see the other question, some solutions repeat the vector, but the last one does not, which is much more efficient.  Apply will not work, it's too slow to loop like that.

Comment: That reutrns all [1] NA NA NA NA

Comment: @bunk Borrowed that in my answer. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: @Frank no that's great1

Comment: @robert, here is an entire vectorized solution below, taking into account the fact that we can permute columns by repeating `vmat` to compare them to columns of `t(M)`

Comment: Did you delete your answer colonel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to @user295691's answer, we merge, but now with `which=TRUE` option in `merge.data.table`:

```
set.seed(1)
matdata  <- create_data(1e6,20,1e5) # using @user295691's example data

library(data.table)
M = as.data.table(matdata$M)
V = as.data.table(matdata$V)

r <- M[V, on=names(V), which=TRUE]
```

To verify that it is correct...

```
V[1,]
#    V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19 V20
# 1:  7  5  3  2  5  6  3  3  5   5   3   2   4   9   4   4   3   6   4   3
M[r[1],]
#    V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19 V20
# 1:  7  5  3  2  5  6  3  3  5   5   3   2   4   9   4   4   3   6   4   3
```

---

**Benchmarks**

OP's example data (in a deleted answer):

```
set.seed(1)

NM    = 1e6
NV    = 1e5
Ncols = 20
MM = matrix(rpois(NM*Ncols,Ncols),NM,Ncols)

rows=sample(NM,NV,replace = FALSE)

Vmat=t(MM[rows,])

# converted to data.frames, because why not?
M = as.data.frame(MM)
V = as.data.frame(t(Vmat))

# converted to data.tables
M2 = setDT(copy(M))
V2 = setDT(copy(V))
```

Functions to test:

```
match_strings <- function(){
  m = do.call(function(...) paste(...,sep="_"), M)
  v = do.call(function(...) paste(...,sep="_"), V)
  match(v,m)
}

merge_df <- function(){ # from @user295691's answer
  M$mid = seq(nrow(M))
  V$vid = seq(nrow(V))
  with(merge(M,V), mid[order(vid)])
}

merge_dt <- function(){
  M2[V2, on=names(V2), which=TRUE]
}
```

Results:

```
system.time({r_strings = match_strings()})
#    user  system elapsed 
#   10.40    0.06   10.49     
system.time({r_merge_df = merge_df()})
#    user  system elapsed 
#   14.71    0.10   14.84
system.time({r_merge_dt = merge_dt()})
#    user  system elapsed 
#    0.39    0.00    0.40 

identical(r_strings,r_merge_df) # TRUE
identical(r_strings,r_merge_dt) # TRUE
```

Comment: So frustrating trying to get 1.9.5 :(

Comment: @robertevansanders But so rewarding! In this case with 1.9.4, you can follow the `merge_df` style with `system.time({M2[, id := .I]; setkeyv(M2,names(V2)); M2[V2]$id -> r}) # .38 seconds for me` and `identical(r, r_strings) # TRUE`

Comment: I have windows which makes life hell haha :(.

Comment: Can you explain what this code does?  I am having a hard time getting it to work.   M2[, id := .I]; setkeyv(M2,names(V2)); M2[V2]$id -> r

Comment: `M2[, id := .I]` creates a row id column in M2 (same as `M$mid = seq(nrow(M))` inside `merge_df`). `setkeyv(M2,names(V2))` prepares `M2` for merging with `V2` by sorting on columns `V1:V20`, which is necessary in data.table 1.9.4. `M2[V2]` does the merge -- each row of the result corresponds to a row of `V2`, so we can just take `$id` and it will be sorted appropriately (unlike in `merge_df`)

Comment: @robertevansanders sorry about that. 1.9.6 is now on CRAN. Perhaps Jan's suggestion about 'drat' is the way to go...

Answer (score 5):

I think collapsing each vector to a single value is the way to go, following @bunk:

```
m = do.call(function(...) paste(...,sep="_"), split(M, col(M)))
v = sapply(list(v1,v2,v3,v4), paste0, collapse="_")
match(v,m)
# [1] 5 4 1 2
```

The more natural way of building `m` would use `apply`, but that's verboten. If you store `M` as a data.frame, another option is:

```
m = do.call(function(...) paste(...,sep="_"), as.data.frame(M))
```

Comment: This is so much faster than the merge solution above.  I am going to post an answer comparing the two answers.  Such a good answer, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If we switch these to `data.frame`s, then we can use `merge` to do the trick.  Also, we rotate `Vmat` for easy matching.

```
haystack <- as.data.frame(M)
haystack$haystack_id <- rownames(haystack)
needle <- as.data.frame(t(Vmat))
needle$needle_id <- rownames(needle)

lookups <- merge(needle, haystack)
lookups <- lookups[order(lookups$needle_id), ]
```

If we compare this to the string/match solution above, it appears to be faster by a reasonable degree

```
create_data <- function(haystack.rows, cols, needle.rows) {
   M <- matrix(rpois(haystack.rows * cols, 5), haystack.rows, cols)
   V <- M[sample(1:haystack.rows, needle.rows, replace=T),]
   list(M=M, V=V)
}

> set.seed(1); data <- create_data(1000000, 20, 10000);
> system.time({haystack <- as.data.frame(data$M); haystack$hid <- seq_along(haystack$V1); needle <- as.data.frame(data$V); needle$nid <- seq_along(needle$V1); ret <- merge(needle, haystack); ret <- ret[order(ret$nid),]})
   user  system elapsed
  5.900   0.000   5.906

> system.time({mstr <- apply(data$M, 1, paste0, collapse="_"); vstr <- apply(data$V, 1, paste0, collapse="_"); matchstr <- match(vstr, mstr)})
   user  system elapsed
  8.372   0.000   8.377
```

`match` on strings is much faster than `merge` but you have to pay the cost of transforming the data, whereas converting to a data frame is very cheap, since it uses the same underlying data.

EDIT: added a sort step to the `merge` version to get the rows in order.  Also fixed a typo in the timed version of the merge version.  Times remained in the same order of magnitude

EDIT2: Thanks to @Frank, found a bug in the `match` version of the time, which sped up things substantially (I had been using a local example called `asdf` which was even larger).  Still not as fast as the `merge` solution, though.

Comment: No need to write your edit notes in the body of the answer. They can be included in the edit summary (a small text field visible when editing). Best to just make your answer into its best version, without documenting its history.

Comment: @Frank: obviously a matter of opinion; I like having the edit notes because while the question is being discussed, I don't like it when things have changed that make my analysis of the answer invalid without warning.  I could probably make a good case for removing the `EDIT` comments once an answer is accepted.

Comment: Fair enough. Might want to add a `identical(ret$hid, matchstr)` to confirm that we're doing the same (presumably right) thing. Pretty standard for benchmarking.

Comment: This speed is compared with Frank's answer , right?  Is there theoretically anything faster than using match?  I don't know much about matching algorithms' computational complexity.

Comment: How is the OP getting reversed results, I wonder. Is their example data substantially different?