# stack every n columns of a matrix without apply in R

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

I have a matrix Vmat:

```
    v1 = c(4  ,  8  ,  3 ,   5 ,   9)       
    v2 = c(5  ,  6  ,  6 ,  11  ,  6)
    v3 = c( 5  ,  6 ,   6 ,  11  ,  6)
    v4=  c(8, 6,  4, 4, 3)
    v5 =  c(4  ,  8  ,  3 ,   5  ,  9)
    v6=  c(8  ,  6  ,  4  ,  4 ,   3)
    v7 = c( 3 ,   2  ,  7   , 7 ,   4)
    v8=  c(3  ,  2   , 7   , 7  ,  4)

row1 = c(v1,v2)
row2 = c(v3,v4)

row3 = c(v5,v6)

row4 = c(v7,v8)

Vmat = rbind(row1,row2,row3,row4)


 Vmat
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
row1    4    8    3    5    9    5    6    6   11     6
row2    5    6    6   11    6    8    6    4    4     3
row3    4    8    3    5    9    8    6    4    4     3
row4    3    2    7    7    4    3    2    7    7     4
```

I want to stack the matrix by dividing it into 2 (n=ncol(Vmat)/2 = every 5 columns).

So the output is:

```
 [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] 
    4    8    3    5    9   
    5    6    6   11    6  
    4    8    3    5    9    
    3    2    7    7    4   
    5    6    6   11     6
    8    6    4    4     3
    8    6    4    4     3
    3    2    7    7     4
```

Comment: Why can apply not be used?

Comment: Because it's too slow, the matrix is massive and I'm doing computationally really demanding stuff

Comment: How massive is massive?

Comment: At the very minimum it will be 2 million columns across and 500 rows, but that is the "toy" example.  The real example will be more like 20 million across and 16,000 rows, probably bigger even.  I want to program it as fast as possible in anticipation

Comment: Is there anything you've already tried yourself, so we know what not to do? I've been toying with it, but even a dummy matrix by your 'toy' example takes up almost all of my 8GB of RAM.

Comment: One possibility would be to convert to `array`, rearrange with `aperm` and then change the dimensions. `n <- 5;ar1 <- array(Vmat, dim=c(4,n,ncol(Vmat)/n)); ar2 <- aperm(ar1, c(1,3,2));dim(ar2) <- c(8,5)`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a potential data.table solution:

```
# install.packages("data.table", type="source")   # requires 1.9.6+
library(data.table)
vm  <- ncol(Vmat)/2
lst <- lapply(1:vm,function(i)c(i,i+vm))
result <- melt(as.data.table(Vmat),measure=lst)[,variable:=NULL]
result
#    value1 value2 value3 value4 value5
# 1:      4      8      3      5      9
# 2:      5      6      6     11      6
# 3:      4      8      3      5      9
# 4:      3      2      7      7      4
# 5:      5      6      6     11      6
# 6:      8      6      4      4      3
# 7:      8      6      4      4      3
# 8:      3      2      7      7      4
```

Using a more realistic example:

```
set.seed(1)
Vmat <- matrix(sample(0:9,16e3*1000,replace=TRUE),nr=16e3)
library(data.table)
system.time({
  vm  <- ncol(Vmat)/2
  lst <- lapply(1:vm,function(i)c(i,i+vm))
  result <- melt(as.data.table(Vmat),measure=lst)[,variable:=NULL]
  })
#    user  system elapsed 
#     0.3     0.0     0.3
```

So, 16,000 rows X 1000 cols takes ~0.3s. Note that while this "uses `lapply(...)`", it is just used to create the `measure.vars` list for `melt(...)`, which does all the work.

@Akrun's solution (same system):

```
system.time({
  n <- ncol(Vmat)/2
  ar1 <- array(Vmat, dim=c(nrow(Vmat),n,ncol(Vmat)/n))
  ar2 <- aperm(ar1, c(1,3,2))
  dim(ar2) <- c(prod(dim(ar1)[c(1,3)]),n)
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#    0.38    0.00    0.37 

all.equal(as.matrix(result),ar2,check.attributes=F)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: BTW, check the dim of your output, you have more columns.

Comment: Then why does `all.equal(...)` return TRUE?

Comment: `dim(result)#
[1] 32000   500; dim(ar2)#
[1] 3200000       5` .  If you are using `check.attributes=FALSE`, I think it will not check the dimensions.

Comment: OK, so maybe I'm misunderstanding the question. I thought OP wanted `ncol(Vmat)/2` columns??

Comment: OP mentioned about every n columns, I think you may have to change the `vm` step.

Answer (score 1):

We could convert the `matrix` to `array`, then transpose the array with `aperm`, and change the dimensions.

```
n <- 5
ar1 <- array(Vmat, dim=c(nrow(Vmat),n,ncol(Vmat)/n))
ar2 <- aperm(ar1, c(1,3,2))
dim(ar2) <- c(prod(dim(ar1)[c(1,3)]),n)
ar2
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    4    8    3    5    9
#[2,]    5    6    6   11    6
#[3,]    4    8    3    5    9
#[4,]    3    2    7    7    4
#[5,]    5    6    6   11    6
#[6,]    8    6    4    4    3
#[7,]    8    6    4    4    3
#[8,]    3    2    7    7    4
```

Using @jlhoward's data,

```
system.time({
  n <- 5
  ar1 <- array(Vmat, dim=c(nrow(Vmat),n,ncol(Vmat)/n))
  ar2 <- aperm(ar1, c(1,3,2))
 dim(ar2) <- c(prod(dim(ar1)[c(1,3)]),n)
})
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.265   0.015   0.279
```

Comment: Isn't this using apply?  If the matrix is enormous this will be slow right?

Comment: You can't compare execution time across systems. Your approach runs in 0.38sec in my system, about 25% slower.

Comment: @jlhoward I didn't compare with your approach.  I was trying to get an estimate of how fast my appraoch runs.  It is more or less similar.

Comment: The difference is trivial with 1000 cols, but with 20MM cols (assuming enough memory, etc.), it is fairly substantial. It is also possible (probable) that the two approaches scale differently.

Comment: @jlhoward It is possible, but I just compared the big data you showed.